# certbot-auto / letsencrypt setting up one key for multiple domains pointing to the same server

Tags: nginx, https, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm really more of a front-end dev so server config stuff is very new territory for me, sorry if this is an easy question!

I'm running into some trouble trying to get my certbot-auto to generate an SSH key for multiple domains, pointing to one box.

I have 3-4 domains (`domain1.net`, `domain2.io`, `domain3.me`, `domain4.codes`), which are all pointing to the same Digital Ocean droplet.

Previously ( couple months back ), I had attempted this with `letsencrypt` directly ( no `certbot` at that time ). Somehow, I got SSL working for all my domains, but they recently expired and I'm now seemingly only able to renew `domain1.net` and not the rest.

I tried the following command:

```
./certbot-auto certonly -a webroot --agree-tos -w /var/www/domain1.net/public_html/ \--expand -d domain1.net,www.domain1.net,domain2.io,www.domain2.io,domain3.me,www.domain3.me,domain4.codes,www.domain4.codes
```

...which SEEMED to work, I got the following:

```
| Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log             │
│ Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org      │
│ Cert not yet due for renewal                                         │
│ Renewing an existing certificate                                     │
│ Performing the following challenges:                                 │
│ http-01 challenge for domain1.net                                    │
│ http-01 challenge for www.domain1.net                                │
│ http-01 challenge for domain2.io                                     │
│ http-01 challenge for www.domain2.io                                 │
│ http-01 challenge for domain3.me                                     │
│ http-01 challenge for www.domain3.me                                 │
│ http-01 challenge for domain4.codes                                  │
│ http-01 challenge for www.domain4.codes                              │
│ Using the webroot path /var/www/domain1.net/public_html for          │
│ all unmatched domains.                                               │
│ Waiting for verification...                                          │
│ Cleaning up challenges                                               │
│ Generating key (2048 bits):                                          │
│ /etc/letsencrypt/keys/0012_key-certbot.pem                           │
│ Creating CSR: /etc/letsencrypt/csr/0012_csr-certbot.pem

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.net/fullchain.pem. Your cert
   will expire on 2017-02-20. To obtain a new or tweaked version of
   this certificate in the future, simply run certbot-auto again. To
   non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
   "certbot-auto renew"
 - If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:

   Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
   Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
```

.. OK Great! however, only `domain1.net` and `www.domain1.net` seem to be working... the other domains claim to not be using HTTPS!

I'm also seeing multiple files in the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/` directory.. I had attempted to get this working previously ( using letsencrypt directly, not via certbot ) and had it working until today, when they expired and refused to renew. this is what I see inside that directory:

```
tom@Personal:/opt$ sudo ls -la /etc/letsencrypt/live/
total 20
drwx------ 5 root root 4096 Nov 22 18:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Nov 22 18:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 22 18:41 domain1.net
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 16 00:00 domain1.net-0001
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 22 18:22 www.domain1.net
```

hmm.. not sure why there are multiple entries in there. shouldn't there just be one?

Anyway -- I'm not well versed enough with HTTPS / keys / NginX to figure this out and am ripping my hair out. I just want to get my SSL keys:

1. working for all the above domains
2. auto-renewing via certbot-auto renew

and not exactly sure where I am messing up here... any help is MUCH appreciated!

EDIT: this is what my server config block looks like in nginx:

```
server {
# listen 80 default_server;
# listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;


  # START LETS ENCRYPT ADDITIONS:
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name domain1.net www.domain1.net domain2.io www.domain2.io domain3.me www.domain3.me domain4.codes www.domain4.codes;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain1.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain1.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
  # /END LETS ENCRYPT ADDITION

  root /var/www/domain1.net/public_html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  # FOR LETSENCRYPT AUTO-RENEWAL, we must give it access to /.well-known
  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
  # /END LETSENCRYPT AUTO_RENEWAL

  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to follow up - I got this working!

Turns out my command was correct but I was misusing the `-d`flag -- it needs to be applied for each domain separately. So the corrected command:

```
./certbot-auto certonly -a webroot --agree-tos -w /var/www/domain1.net/public_html/ \--expand -d domain1.net,www.domain1.net  -d domain2.io,www.domain2.io -d domain3.me,www.domain3.me -d domain4.codes,www.domain4.codes
```

Comment: Great! But what if you have over 100 domains? Could you still do it this way through 1 certificate with lets encrypt? I understand if you don't know the answer.